# Linux shows one partition but windows shows 4

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation

I have installed Windows 8 on my laptop and now I want to install Linux Mint 14. I want to use both of them. My disk management in Windows shows as follows:

[image: picture].

mint4win in linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-64bit is used to do the install. Then I shut down Windows and open Linux Mint. However, during the install process a wizard shows the whole hard disk as one partition.

I used a DVD an a USB other than mint4win. But it gives the same result.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the wizard during the mint installation? A picture with your phone would suffice.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, the installer is likely only showing you linux related partitions. There might of been an option earlier to show all types of partitions. The mint installers that I've used in the past presented a choice like this: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=122276

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [mint4win](https://github.com/linuxmint/mint4win) installer based on Wubi. This creates a hard file in *Windows* for installation:

> Wubi is the Windows Linux Mint Installer. Wubi installs Linux Mint
>   inside a file within a Windows partition, and thus it does not require
>   CD burning or dedicated partitions, yet the installation is a dual
>   boot setup identical to a normal installation.

You should probably boot the DVD or make a bootable USB out of the image to access the classic installer at boot time.

Comment: question updated.

Comment: @ddarz4u As slm explained, there should be either an option like "something else" or a link to "advanced partitioning configuration" in one of the install dialogs. Maybe try having a 10GB+ unassigned free space block on the drive to see if the options change during install?